# NPM 7 workspaces with babel - importing between workspaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I've stumbled across an issue while using NPM 7 workspaces and Babel where I can't wrap my head around the best way to be able to `import` from `src/` during development but use `dist/` during production.

Apologies for my awful explanation, I'll just do an example (this excludes config files and such for brevity):

My project structure is like so:

```
- /
  - lambdas/lambda-a
    - src/
    - package.json
  - packages/package-a
    - src/
    - package.json
  - package.json
```

I have my `main` field in `packages/package-a/package.json` like so:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "src/index.js",
  ...
}
```

Which means I can import stuff from `packages/package-a` just fine in `lambdas/lambda-a/src/index.js`:

```
import { thing } from '<package-a>'
```

However, by having the `main` field pointing to `src/index.js`, this isn't going to work in production, and if I change the `main` field to `dist/index.js` I can no longer import in `lambdas/lambda-a` during development without running a build after every change.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Or, more likely, can anyone point out where I'm being a muppet?

Comment: We're having the same issue, and I haven't found a viable solution.  The one that I've heard is to have the build process dump directly into the root folder - which just seems terrible.  However, as far as I know it's the only solution due to how NPM resolves those paths.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I use is to replace `src/index.js` before building and replacing it again after building/packing is done. This is neither elegant nor "how you should do it" (AFAIK), but it works for me in a small project.

I use [npe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npe) because it's lightweight but there are similar (or more powerful) packages out there.

Example (`packages/package-a/package.json`):

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "npe": "^1.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
  "build:before": "npe main dist/index.js'",
  "build": "(npm run build:before) && (if exist dist rmdir /s /q dist) && (babel src -d dist --copy-files) && (npm pack) && (npm run build:after)",
  "build:after": "npe main src/index.js",
},
...
```

But I'm also still searching for a more "official" way...